# Why angularjs scoping is allow access variable before initialization

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

When executing this snippet in angular js included html file.

`<p>{{a}} remains {{a = 2;}}</p>`

It didn't through reference error exception.

But angularjs is descendant or built over plain vanilla js why this subtlity.

Here is the equivalent code in plain js.

```
alert(a);
a = 2;
```

As my expectation while executing this it through reference error exception but why not angularjs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your first angular template snippet is not a direct declaration of javascript, it's evaluated by angular's template engine. And also, it doesn't produce javascript errors output because when you first write `{{a}}` you create a template engine output for a variable `a` in scope, which is undefined at that moment. But then, when you write `{{ a = 2; }}` you touch the scope to declare `a`, wich makes angular engine to redraw the snippet and apply a new binded value and produce a valid output on the `{{a}}` snippet.

For example:

```
<p ng-controller="AppCtrl">{{a}} remains {{ declare(); }}</p>

angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('AppCtrl', 
    ['$scope', '$timeout',
      function ($scope, $timeout) {
        $scope.declare = function (){
          $timeout(function(){$scope.a = 2;}, 2000);

        }
  }]);
```

This code at a first moment will produce `remains` and 2 seconds after the template evaluation, will produce `2 remains`.